# Sql creating table consisting of keys from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is probably a simple question but I am quite new to SQL and databases, so I have been following this site: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/ to try and create a table that consist of primary keys from other tables.

Here I have the structure of the database in an excel overview. With colors showing the relations.  i am having problems with the One-To-Many tables. As I get the same error every time "ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
SQL state: 42703".
[image: The table structure, colorized for relations]

The SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient_to_unit_relations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingrediens;


CREATE TABLE ingrediens (
  id serial,
  name_of_ingredient varchar(255),
  price_per_unit int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ingredient_to_unit_relations (
  ingredient_relation_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_relation_id),
    constraint Fk_ingredient_id
        FOREIGN KEY (id) 
            REFERENCES ingrediens (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the column in order to declare it as a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient_to_unit_relations (
  ingredient_relation_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  ingredient_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_relation_id),
  constraint Fk_ingredient_id FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingrediens (id)
);
```

I might recommend some somewhat different naming conventions (I changed the name `id` in the table above):

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
  ingredient_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255),
  price_per_unit int
);

CREATE TABLE ingredient_to_unit_relations (
  ingredient_relation_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ingredient_id int,
  CONSTRAINT Fk_ingredient_id FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredients (ingredient_id)
);
```

Notes:

- I am a fan of naming primary keys after the table they are in.  That way, foreign keys and primary keys usually have the same name (and you can use `using` if you choose).
- Avoid `SERIAL`.  `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` is now recommended.
- You can inline primary key constraints (as well as other constraints).
- There is not generally a need to repeat the table name in a column (other than the primary key).  So, `name` instead of `name_of_ingredient`.
- Using `int` for a monetary column is suspicious.  It doesn't allow smaller units.  That might work for some currencies but in general I would expect a `numeric`/`decimal` type.

Comment: What if i want to add multiple relations as shown in the picture ? and thanks for the insane answer really opened up my eyes

Comment: @AskeM.  . . . You can declare multiple foreign keys for a given table.